# Shuffling documents/fields from firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a solution for the quiz program I am developing.
1. There are 10 questions in 10 documents under a Question Collection. 
2. Each of these questions have 1 correct answer and 5 wrong options.

This is what I have done so far: 
1. I have a ListView in a Linear Layout (apart from the Textviews to show Questions and Options:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/queslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

    </ListView>
```

In the Java code, I have an adapter which is populated with all the documents in the Questions Collection like this.

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, questions);
    quesList.setAdapter(adapter);
    chapterRef.document(chapterBase)
            .collection(levelBase)
            .document("Summary")
            .collection("QUESTIONS")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                        quesFull = documentSnapshot.getString("ques");
                        questions.add(quesFull);
                        Toast("questions "+questions);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

So far so good. Now I would like to achieve this:

When the user opts for the quiz, 
1. All 10 questions are shuffled so that their order is never the same for another user.
2. Secondly, I wish to randomly select any 3 wrong options (from the 5 wrong options).
This makes the options totally 4 (including the right answer). 
3. Finally, I wish to shuffle these 4 options again so that the sequence is different for every try.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For those who would be looking at an answer for a similar issue, here's how went about resolving it. 
If, however, someone has a better solution, would appreciate if it can be shared here.

I first created a List String = questions and then added the numbers to it. Ofcourse, this can be further improved upon.

Then, I called the method QuestionShuffle.

```
private void QuestionShuffle() {

    questions.add("1");
    questions.add("2");
    questions.add("3");
    questions.add("4");
    questions.add("5");
    questions.add("6");
    questions.add("7");
    questions.add("8");
    questions.add("9");
    questions.add("10");

    Collections.shuffle(questions);
}
```

Using the .get(index), I then got the shuffled sequence of the questions.

```
String docnumber = questions.get(counter);
```

And for shuffling the Options, the following code was used.

```
private void OptionShuffle(){
    Random random = new Random();
    List<String> givenList = Lists.newArrayList("0", "1", "2", "3", "4");
    int numOfopts = 3;
    options.clear();

  for(int i = 0; i < numOfopts; i++){

        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(givenList.size());
        String selection = givenList.get(randomIndex);
        options.add(optList.get(Integer.parseInt(selection)));
        givenList.remove(randomIndex);
    }

    optionA.setText(ansFull);
    options.add(ansFull);
    Collections.shuffle(options);
    optionA.setText(options.get(0));
    optionB.setText(options.get(1));
    optionC.setText(options.get(2));
    optionD.setText(options.get(3));

}
```